# typeof Javascript constantly returning string for DOM

Tags: javascript

I have an input box that looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="enter name">
```

And I assign it to a variable like so: (this occurs through a submit button activating a function)

```
var name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
```

However, when I use typeof:

```
var check = typeof bid;
      console.log(check);
```

It always logs a string, no matter if I input a number or a string.

I assume I'm missing something, so I'd love someone to offer an input. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Value read from DOM is always string

Comment: Is there any way to counter that? @rajesh

Comment: `parseInt`, `parseFloat`, `Number`. You will have to manually parse them

Comment: Sorry. Didn't read it all. It explains parseFloat @Rajesh

Comment: I'll have a look and see if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since everything you get from DOM is string, you can use **isNumeric** in jQuery. Link to doc: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

Comment: `isNumeric` is used to validate if value is numeric or not. It will not convert to number. Also, OP has not tagged `jQuery` in question. Recommending an approach based on a library not mentioned can go against you.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: isNumeric tests for "", and in my case "" are included in the output of the input box, so it works out. @Rajesh

Comment: @CasparBroekhuizen Glad your problem is solved. You can also look into `isNaN` if you are not happy adding a lib to your solution